# How to access PC on subnet router in this set up?

Tags: windows, networking, router, home-networking

I have the following network at home

### Network

[image]

### ISP Router settings

[image]

### Subnet-Router settings

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to make **PC 3** see and access shared files on **PC 1** and **PC 2** and vice versa, keeping all existing IP assignments? All PCs are Windows.

Thank you.

Comment: This seems quite complicated for a very small network. Make sure LAN1 and LAN2 in the ISP modem/router are on the same subnet. Put your own Router on the same subnet as LAN1,2 and turn DHCP OFF on your own router. Make sure Wireless Isolation is OFF on your ISP modem/router.  Goal: All devices on one subnet and then they will all talk to each other. I have that running here.

Comment: @John. There are more PCs attached to the Switch and Subnet-Router (which I've omitted for the sake of simplicity.)  The thing is that PCs connected via Subnet-Router must be kept on a separate network and IP assignments entirely, as I mentioned int he post, for various reasons. Do you think it can still be done? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to put routing in place to connect subnets. There are a variety of articles on network routing available on the internet. Network routing can be a bit picky and where we have separate subnets, there has not been a need to connect them.

Comment: Here is a sample article for you to consider:  https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linking_Subnets_with_Static_Routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complicated solution is to configure routing tables in all the computers.
The simple solution is to have everybody on the same network.

The only problem with that is the DHCP allocation of IP addresses,
where you can:

- Let the ISP router do DHCP; disable this function on the other router and
  the switch
- Configure multiple DHCP servers with a distinct segment each
  for allocating IP addresses.
  If needed, the network can be `192.168.x.x/16` and the DHCP servers
  will allocate from `192.168.1.x`, `192.168.2.x` etc.